# Scanned PDF to Searchable PDF Android

Tags: android, pdf

How do I convert a scanned pdf book (380 pages) to a text searchable pdf?

Only have access to an android phone. Online websites will do as long as they can do every page. 
Even mere help would be good.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! While waiting for good recommendations, maybe you want to take a look at [my related app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf#group_115) and try one of the apps supporting OCR (that's what you're after: Optical Character Recognition, to make the resulting PDF searchable)? As I'm not using any of those, I cannot give a recommendation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the file in Google Drive and wait a bit. OCR will happen automatically.